# Concise way to return a new array of N elements filled with iterated values from another array? Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a given array with an undetermined quantity of elements, the array can be numbers or strings, then I need to generate a new array of N elements made from the iterated elements of the first array

I already have a function to do it, but it only works if the original array are consecutive numbers, it doesn't work with strings. I have a gazillion of ideas on how to achieve it. I could just concatenate the array to a new one until its equal or greater than the required quantity of elements, and then set the new array length to the required quantity, but is there a more concise and elegant way to do it?

IDEA 01 [codepen](https://codepen.io/aalvarados/pen/RwNZXYY)

```js
function populateArray(qty) {
  // Array to populate from
  let array = [1,2,3];
  //Determine the Range Length of the array and assign it to a variable
  let min = array[0];
  let max = array[array.length - 1];
 const rangeLength = (max - min + 1);
 //Initialize uniqueArray which will contain the concatenated array
 let uniqueArray = [];
 //Test if quantity is greater than the range length and if it is,
    //concatenate the array to itself until the new array has equal number of elements or greater
 if (qty > rangeLength) {
  //Create an array from the expansion of the range
  let rangeExpanded = Array.from(new Array(rangeLength), (x,i) => i + min);
  while (uniqueArray.length < qty) {
   uniqueArray = uniqueArray.concat(rangeExpanded);
  }
 }
  // Remove additional elements
  uniqueArray.length = qty
 return uniqueArray;
}

console.log(populateArray(13))
```

IDEA 02 [codepen](https://codepen.io/aalvarados/pen/dyPzBqp), but it fills the new array 13 times with the whole original array, not iterated items

```js
// FILL A NEW ARRAY WITH N ELEMENTS FROM ANOTHER ARRAY
let array = [1,2,3];
let length = 13;
let result = Array.from( { length }, () => array );
                        
console.log(result);
```

the expected result is [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1] if the original array were made of strings the expected result would be [dog,cat,sheep,dog,cat,sheep,dog,cat,sheep,dog,cat,sheep,dog]

Comment: I just reminded why the first function needs rangeLength and rangeExpanded, the server just gives me starting value and ending value, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go with @CertainPerformance's answer. But here's a different approach, just for *thinking-out-of-the-box* purposes

```
// A function for getting an index up to length's size 
function getIDX(idx, length){
return idx <= length ? idx : getIDX(idx-length, length); 
}


const newArrayLength = 13;
const sourceArray = [1,2,3];
const resultArray = [];
for(let i=0; i< newArrayLength; i++){
resultArray[i]=sourceArray[getIDX(i+1, sourceArray.length)-1];
}
```

**EDIT 1**:
I was comparing the performance of this approach versus the others here described and it seems that if you wanted to create a very large new array (ex: newArrayLength= 10000) the  `getIDX()` function takes a lot to finish because of the size of the call stack. So I've improved the `getIDX()` function by removing the recursion and now the complexity is O(1) check it out:

```
function getIDX(idx, length){
if (length === 1) {return idx};
const magicNumber = length * (Math.ceil(idx/length)-1);
 return idx - magicNumber;
}
```

With the new `getIDX()` function this approach seems to be the most performant.
You can take a look to the tests here:
https://jsbench.me/v7k4sjrsuw/1

Comment: Good job, nice recursion. As you said, to think out of the box.

Comment: WOW, even the generator is up to 40% slower. I did run independent benchmarks from the ones you sent. I still won't go with @CertainPerformance answer, it can be one liner but flat is only supported from chrome 69. Still doing tests for now. Yours look more elegant. But I think in your solution performance is tricked. running the for loop without a function looks like a bad practice. I converted the loop to a pure function and it is 50.48% slower https://codepen.io/aalvarados/pen/bGNopJg

Comment: I'll investigate further and edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can tweak your second idea a bit - calculate the number of times you need to repeat the initial array to come up with the required number of total items, then flatten it and `.slice`:

```js
let array = [1,2,3];
let length = 13;
const fromLength = Math.ceil(length / array.length);
let result = Array.from( { length: fromLength }, () => array )
  .flat()
  .slice(0, length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: good and thank you very much it works as expected. Anyway in the example 2 i asked if it could be iterated and probably the function needs a map so I can transform each iterated item.

Comment: With this method, since you're flattening, there doesn't look to be any need for transforming otherwise, right?

Comment: Probably I would remove fromLength and slice it anyway to keep it concise, need to test performance with big arrays. On the other hand Imagine on each iteration I prepend or append something to each array element, imagine if the original array were [dog, sheep, cow] then the new array would be [black-dog, black-sheep, black-cow, pink-dog, pink-sheep, pink-cow, green-dog...] or even random generated values prepended to each iterated item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) that will create a repeating sequence from an input. You can add a limit to the generated sequence and simply turn it into an array:

```js
function* repeatingSequence(arr, limit) {
  for(let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    const index = i % arr.length;
    yield arr[index];
  }
}

const generator = repeatingSequence(["dog", "cat", "sheep"], 10);

const result = Array.from(generator);

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively, you can make an infinite repeating sequence with no limit and then generate as many elements as you want for an array:

```js
function* repeatingSequence(arr) {
  let i = 0
  while(true) {
    const index = i % arr.length;
    yield arr[index];
    i++;
  }
}

const generator = repeatingSequence(["dog", "cat", "sheep"]);

const result = Array.from({length: 10}, () => generator.next().value);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `modulo` operator. Special thanks to [@Vlaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) for shorten version:

```
Array.from({ length:length }, (e, i) => array[ i  % array.length ])
```

An example:

```js
let array = [1,2,3];
let length = 13;
const result = Array.from({ length:length }, 
    (e, i) => array[ i  % array.length ]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `array[i] ? array[i] : array[ i  % array.length ]` what is the benefit of the conditional operator over a simple `array[ i  % array.length ]`? For `i < array.length` : `i === i % array.length`, so the first branch seems rather useless.

Comment: @VLAZ you are right! I was in hurry! Thank you very much for the great comment! I've updated the answer!:)