# Loop through array multiple times

Tags: javascript

How do I repeat the `colors` array in order, given an unknown length of `items`?

```
const items = [1, 2, ...n]
const colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red']

// return ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'green'] where items.length = 5
```

Comment: What is the significance of the *content* in `items` here? You only seem to use its length...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concise way to return a new array of N elements filled with iterated values from another array? Vanilla JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59529059/concise-way-to-return-a-new-array-of-n-elements-filled-with-iterated-values-from)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8]
const colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red']

const result = items.map((_,i) => colors[i%colors.length]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfect! I was stuck in a block. Many thanks!

Edit: I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm allowed :)

Answer (score 3):

You can map over a new array with the length you want and take the modulus of the index by the length of the `colors` array. You do not seem to need the `items` array at all.

```js
let len = 5;
const colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red'];
const res = Array(len).fill().map((_,idx)=>colors[idx % colors.length]);
console.log(res);
```

`Array.from` can also be used in this case.

```js
let length = 5;
const colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red'];
const res = Array.from({length}, (_,idx)=>colors[idx % colors.length]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Or similarly, `Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i) => colors[i % colors.length])`

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new array and map the values by using the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder).

```js
const
    items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red'],
    result = Array.from(items, (_, i) => colors[i % colors.length]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Do you find this cleaner than a `map` call?

Comment: yes, because it take only a part structure (the length) of the original array. by using `map`, i miss the part where an element is used for the result. (this may apply here as well ...)

Answer (score 3):

When the target size is large, you may get better performance by doubling the array over and over again:

```js
function stretch(arr, n) {
  while (arr.length < n) arr = arr.concat(arr);
  return arr.slice(0, n);
}

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red'];

console.log(stretch(colors, items.length));
```

Comment: A nice approach for a large array.  For clarity, I would choose a `map` / `Array.from` solution over this unless I expected large arrays.  But when wanted, this is quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can take mode for index so you can repeat it.

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3,4,5,6];
const colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red'];

var result=[];
items.forEach(myFunction)

function myFunction(item, index) {
  console.log(colors[(index%colors.length)])
  result.push(colors[(index%colors.length)])
}
```

Comment: That's a `map` in disguise.  You might as well just use it directly.

Comment: Now you have a function with side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Using map()

```js
const  items  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red'];
output = items.map((_,i) => colors[i % colors.length])
     
console.log(output);
```

Comment: What does the spread add here?  See the answer from Ali for comparison.

Comment: I'm suggesting that your same code would work if you removed the initial `[...` and trailing `]`.  The `map` call already creates a new array that does what we want.  The spread is entirely superfluous.

Comment: You can also remove True or Correct from your last comment!